# Match email sender field with a user ID google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm working on an application that lets users interact with their account by sending emails to a specific address.  The app is on GAE and I'm writing it in python.  Here's my question:

When I receive an email from a user the sender field is text.  I want to run a datastore query and match the userID to the sender's email address, but for some reason I can't match the string (sender) to the UserID in the datastore.  Here's my code.

```
class MailHandler (InboundMailHandler):
  def receive(self, message):
    sender = message.sender
    user_account = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Task WHERE user = :1", sender).fetch(5)
```

This is returning None for the user account, despite the fact that the sender email address matches the user in the Task table.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the model definition for Task?

Comment: Is User ID an email? Or is it a UserProperty? If it's a UserProperty, the documentation states: "Within the datastore, the value is equal to the email address plus the user's unique ID."

Comment: It's a UserProperty.  Thanks, I'm not sure how I missed that.